# python Traits: Column of Buttons in Table

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

I would like to add a Button to the end of every line in a table.

The following code results in an PyDeadObjectError when closing the window:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits,Str,Int,Button,Instance
from traitsui.api import TableEditor,ObjectColumn,View
class Person(HasTraits):
    name=Str
    age=Int
    Plot_size=Button(label='Plot size')

class Display(HasTraits):
    table=List(Instance(Person))
    table_editor=TableEditor(columns=[ObjectColumn(name='name'),
        ObjectColumn(name='age'),
        ObjectColumn(name='Plot_size')],
        deletable = True,
        sortable = False,
        sort_model = False,
        show_lines = True,
        orientation = 'vertical',
        show_column_labels = True)
    traits_view=View(Item('table',editor=table_editor),resizable=True)

a=Display()
a.table.append(Person(name='Joe',age=21))
a.table.append(Person(name='John',age=27))
a.table.append(Person(name='Jenny',age=23))
a.configure_traits()
```

Has someone already tried to do the same? How can I get rid of this error? Is it possible to display the Button even without clicking on the corresponding cell?

Comment: I've noticed that this only generates the PyDeadObjectError on close if the user attempts to interact with the "Plot_size" column before closing the window. Any thoughts on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is there but there is perhaps a workaround. Instead of having a column full of buttons, have one button and then use the selected row.

```
from traits.api import HasTraits,Str,Int,Button,Instance, List
from traitsui.api import TableEditor,ObjectColumn,View, Item

class Person(HasTraits):
    name=Str
    age=Int
    #Plot_size=Button(label='Plot size')


class Display(HasTraits):
    Plot_size=Button(label='Plot size')
    selected_person = Instance(Person)

    people=List(Instance(Person))
    table_editor=TableEditor(columns=[ObjectColumn(name='name'),
        ObjectColumn(name='age')],
        selected='selected_person',
        #ObjectColumn(name='Plot_size', editable=False)],
        deletable = True,
        sortable = False,
        sort_model = False,
        show_lines = True,
        orientation = 'vertical',
        show_column_labels = True)

    traits_view=View(Item('people',editor=table_editor),
            Item('Plot_size'),
            resizable=True)

    def _Plot_size_fired(self):
            print self.selected_person.name

demo=Display(people = [Person(name='Joe',age=21),
    Person(name='John',age=27),
    Person(name='Jenny',age=23)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo.configure_traits()
```

Otherwise, maybe the checkbox_column example is a good place to start.

Comment: I took a look at the checkbox_column and a workaround is possible(displaying a Checkbox instead of a Button). However, to write a "ButtonColumn" class based on CheckboxColumn seems quite difficult, because CheckboxColumn uses a special renderer which, it seems to me, is not available for the Button class. I guess I would have to dig deeper into the code to get a ButtonColumn working...

Comment: Yes, I thought to adapt CheckboxColumn but it seems like a lot of work. I think the problem is that a button is an event trait so doesn't store a value. Displaying something without a value in a table is a strange idea, although I can see why you might want buttons in a table. Good luck!

Comment: Thx...I guess I will try to work out a solution with a checkboxcolumn and a single button on top of the table to perform the action I want on all the selected lines. Cheers!